# Loading a VCLSTYLE from a resource in a BPL

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

Using Embarcadero C++Builder XE7.

We have placed a few styles into a resource. The styles have been added using the "Project -> Resources and Images" dialog. The resulting `.rc` file looks like this:

```
Auric VCLSTYLE "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\15.0\\Redist\\styles\\vcl\\Auric.vsf"
Carbon VCLSTYLE "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\15.0\\Redist\\styles\\vcl\\Carbon.vsf"
```

During build, I can see the resource is built and linked.

I would like to now access this from my main application, which has linked to this lib, using `TStyleManager::Styles`. No matter if I include the RC directly, or put it in a BPL and load it with `LoadPackage()`, However, it only returns the Windows style, not the ones listed above. How do I get the main application to load these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the aforementioned RC file by hand to the library (or application directly), so that it could be compiled by the resource compiler into a RES file and linked into BPL (or into the application executable), I needed to add

```
#include <Vcl.Themes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Styles.hpp>
```

in the application. Otherwise, even though the RC is linked correctly, the styles are not accessible at runtime.

Comment: Static `.lib` files do not contain resources, only code. You can add the `.res` file, or even the `.rc` file itself, to your app project using the Project Manager (an `.rc` file will be automatically compiled into a `.res` file). The resource will then be linked into the final `.exe`.  You definitely SHOULD NOT be **deploying** your `.res` file onto remote machines. If you want to use deployable resources that are not linked directly into the `.exe`, they should be compiled into a `.dll` that the `.exe` loads at runtime.

Comment: adding to Remy's comment, it's also possible to specify a custom build line for resource files (select the .rc file in the Project Manager after adding it, and then look in the Properties pane)